# log4j2 does not work with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, war, log4j2

I have a Web Application delpoyed to the Tomcat Server. It has to log something to a file. When I do the same from a standalone application, it works (logs to file, to console, whatever), but nothing happens from Tomcat.

Here's my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">D:/tmp/logs/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/myexample.log"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}- [%c{1}]: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="info"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Console" level="info"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

in my `web.xml` I tried relative path to it, absolute, no change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


        <context-param>
            <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
            <param-value>D:\Utils\Apache\Tomcat\webapps\synchronize\WEB-INF/log4j2.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>SynchServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>ds.synch.SynchServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SynchServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/synch</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I also tried putting my `log4j2.xml` configurational file into `classes` directory in Tomcat -- still no output to my file or `stdout` file of Tomcat.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where I was wrong, and it's pretty stupid, I forgot to add `log4j-web` to tomcat's classpath

Comment: you mean tomcat under lib folder or in project pom.xml? can you please tell me ?